# How can I find the best X variables to satisfy the conditions of Y using Bayesian search or Grid search in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to write a code to find the best X variables satisfying the condition of the Y variable.
The CSV file is based on the simulation of the S11&S21 parameter by changing LC width&length.

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m04vY.png)

[Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZTV.png)

[Corr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSByx.png)

There is 22 X variables (LC Width&length) and 4 Y variable (Min&Max of S11/S21 of looking range frequency).

```
def custom_scorer(estimator, X, y_true, **kwargs):
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    
    Min_S11_5GHz = (y_pred[:, 0] - y_true[:, 0]).sum()
    Max_S21_5GHz = (-y_pred[:, 1] + y_true[:, 1]).sum()
    Max_S11_5_945_7_125GHz = (-y_pred[:, 2] + y_true[:, 2]).sum()
    Min_S21_5_945_7_125GHz = (y_pred[:, 3] - y_true[:, 3]).sum()

    return Min_S11_5GHz + Max_S21_5GHz + Max_S11_5_945_7_125GHz + Min_S21_5_945_7_125GHz

#Higher Min_S11_5GHz is better score
#Smaller Max_S21_5GHz is better score
#Max_S11_5.945-7.125GHz is better score
#Min_S21_5.945-7.125GHz is better score
```

I'm thinking about Gaussian kernel regression (or MLR) and Bayesian search to find the best X variables (LC Width&length) satisfying the condition of the Y variable.

EX): C length: 0.5cm, C Width: 0.4cm, L length: 0.5cm, L Width: 0.4cm is the best score.

Is Bayesian optimizing search good to find it?
As my study, Bayesian optimizing search or Grid search is to find the parameter of modeling.
Are these search available to find the best X variables?

If not, please give me an advice.

Here is my full code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Read and combine all CSV files
combined_data = []
for file_name in os.listdir("dataset"):
  if file_name.endswith(".csv"):
    file_path = os.path.join("dataset", file_name)
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0)
    combined_data.append(data)

combined_df = pd.concat(combined_data)

# Separate each graph
graphs = [combined_df.iloc[i:i + 1951] for i in range(0, len(combined_df), 1951)]

# Create a new DataFrame to store the required values
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(combined_df.columns) + ['Min_S11_5GHz', 'Max_S21_5GHz', 'Max_S11_5.945-7.125GHz', 'Min_S21_5.945-7.125GHz'])

for graph in graphs:
  row_result = graph.iloc[0, :23]
  graph = graph.copy()
  graph['Frequency (GHz)'] = pd.to_numeric(graph['Frequency (GHz)'])

  # Find min(S11) and max(S21) for frequency <= 5
  range_5_GHz = graph.loc[graph['Frequency (GHz)'] <= 5.0]
  row_result['Min_S11_5GHz'] = range_5_GHz['S11'].min()
  row_result['Max_S21_5GHz'] = range_5_GHz['S21'].max()

  # Find max(S11) and min(S21) for 5.945 <= frequency <= 7.125
  range_5_945_7_125_GHz = graph.loc[(graph['Frequency (GHz)'] >= 5.945) & (graph['Frequency (GHz)'] <= 7.125)]
  row_result['Max_S11_5.945-7.125GHz'] = range_5_945_7_125_GHz['S11'].max()
  row_result['Min_S21_5.945-7.125GHz'] = range_5_945_7_125_GHz['S21'].min()

  # Append the result into the result DataFrame
  result_df = pd.concat([result_df, row_result.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)


# Remove first, 24th, and 25th columns
result_df_cleaned = result_df.drop(columns=['Frequency (GHz)', 'S11', 'S21'])

# Save the cleaned DataFrame to a CSV file
result_df_cleaned.to_csv('results_cleaned.csv', index=False)

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from skopt.space import Real, Integer, Categorical

# Separate X and Y variables
X_variables = result_df_cleaned.columns[:22]
Y_variables = result_df_cleaned.columns[22:]
X_data = result_df_cleaned[X_variables]
Y_data = result_df_cleaned[Y_variables]

# Define a custom scoring function to measure how well a model satisfies your constraints
def custom_scorer(estimator, X, y_true, **kwargs):
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    
    Min_S11_5GHz = (y_pred[:, 0] - y_true[:, 0]).sum()
    Max_S21_5GHz = (-y_pred[:, 1] + y_true[:, 1]).sum()
    Max_S11_5_945_7_125GHz = (-y_pred[:, 2] + y_true[:, 2]).sum()
    Min_S21_5_945_7_125GHz = (y_pred[:, 3] - y_true[:, 3]).sum()

    return Min_S11_5GHz + Max_S21_5GHz + Max_S11_5_945_7_125GHz + Min_S21_5_945_7_125GHz

scorer = make_scorer(custom_scorer, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=False, needs_threshold=False)
```